# matlab frames undergo change in pixel value after reconstruction. how to avoid this?

Tags: matlab, video, frames

I would like to extend my project on image watermarking to video, using prediction and sorting method.For that, in simple words, I want to process each frame, make some changes in the pixel values at sender side, reconstruct the video from the modified frames and want to revoke all those changes in pixels at the receiver side. My problem is that when the video is reconstructed after editing the frames the pixel values change again. i tested it with the code given below. ( i didnt make any modification to pixels, just read from the first video, write that frames to another video in same format and checked the pixel values of 1st frames of both videos)

```
readerobj = VideoReader('produce.mp4');
vidFrames = read(readerobj);
numFrames = get(readerobj, 'NumberOfFrames')

outputVideo = VideoWriter('produce_new','MPEG-4');
outputVideo.FrameRate = readerobj.FrameRate;
open(outputVideo);
q=1;
x=read(readerobj,q);
for q=1:numFrames
    frames=read(readerobj,q);
    frame_store=frames;
    writeVideo(outputVideo,frame_store); 
end

close(outputVideo);

readerobj = VideoReader('produce_new.mp4');
vidFrames = read(readerobj);
numFrames = get(readerobj, 'NumberOfFrames')
q=1;
y=read(readerobj,q);
count=0;

for i=1:size(x,1)
     for j=1:size(x,2)
          if x(i,j)~=y(i,j)
             count=count+1;
          end 
     end
```

end
   count

the value of count, which indicate the number of pixels underwent a change in value after video reconstruction is huge. In fact, for my code to work correctly, no pixel value should be changed. Is there a solution to this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MPEG-4 is not lossless, at least it's not with the way `VideoWriter` uses it here.

Try setting the `profile` argument to `'Archival'` when creating the `VideoWriter` (i.e. `writerObj = VideoWriter(filename,profile)`);

> `profile`
>
> String enclosed in single quotation marks that describes the type of file to create. Specifying a profile sets default values for video properties such as `VideoCompressionMethod`. Possible values:
>
> `'Archival'` Motion JPEG 2000 file with lossless compression
>
> `'Motion JPEG AVI'` Compressed AVI file using Motion JPEG codec
>
> `'Motion JPEG 2000'` Compressed Motion JPEG 2000 file
>
> `'MPEG-4'` Compressed MPEG-4 file with H.264 encoding (systems with Windows 7 or Mac OS X 10.7 and later)
>
> `'Uncompressed AVI'` Uncompressed AVI file with RGB24 video

However, `'Archival'` will give a huge file, while **`'MPEG-4'` will give the best compression-quality compromise**, if your system supports H.264 encoding. For the lossy compression methods (e.g. `'MPEG-4'` or `'Motion JPEG AVI'`), using a higher `Quality` setting will help the quality, but the pixel values will *not* be the same not matter high how the quality is set.

Note that with lossless compression, the `Quality` option is not used.

---

NOTE: To count the number of different pixels without a loop:

```
count = sum(x(:)==y(:))
```

Comment: sir , number of frames of both videos are same, pixel values are exactly the same, so what does it mean when you say that the reconstructed file obtained using 'archival' profile would be larger than the original one? ...

Comment: @user3197936 The file size on disk would be bigger than if you used MPEG-4